# Reply to email, see old email content/reference. Do I have to add it manually?

Tags: php, laravel, email, zend-framework, imap

I am unsing zend-mail to reply to emails and laravel-imap to retrieve emails.

I found that I need to set email headers `In-Reply-To` and `References` if I want to get the reply/answer chain.

I made a test through the web interface. I send 3 emails/replies. If I access the most recent email with laravel-imap it looks like this:

[image]

I just get the HTML body. The blockquotes are already there.
The relevant header data looks like this:

```
in_reply_to: "<384147642.238334.1576579700275@ox.hosteurope.de>"
message_id: "<320022621.238341.1576579713511@ox.hosteurope.de>"
references: "<1031599702.238330.1576579685138@ox.hosteurope.de> <384147642.238334.1576579700275@ox.hosteurope.de>"
```

Now I do exactly the same in my application. I use zend-mail to send/reply to emails. But If I get the HTML body I only see:

```
Web 2
```

In my case the relevant header data looks correct aswell:

```
in_reply_to: "<59b58fd747e1155deb1f3ab9b8050607b6e52897@localhost.eu>"
message_id: "<e17eadb481c0c538289a8bf3190da409f3ede695@localhost.eu>"
references: "<bccc37f17dc69b9811ed59c75b3e466d08b1a9d5@localhost.eu> <59b58fd747e1155deb1f3ab9b8050607b6e52897@localhost.eu>"
```

---

So where is my problem? I remember reading that the HTML body with references is created automatically if references are set, which they are in my case.

Or should I manually append contents of the referenced email into the textarea if I reply to an email?

Comment: The headers link them together, via threading.  If you want to include the contents of the email, you have to do it yourself  It's not part of the protocol.

Comment: @Max thank you for the reply. Its really not easy to find information on this topic. I thought so already too. Have been testing now with multple different email providers and everyone handles the quoted content differently, which indicates that referenced mail content is added manually. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Max Do I understand this correctly. These headers (references, in_reply_to) are seen as "database" entries in case something is wrong with the displayed content. I could always use the references ID's to reproduce the reply chain.

Comment: Those headers are so that email clients can show them as related emails (a thread or conversation) automatically, they're for machines to handle.  The stuff in the body is for the the human's convenience.

Comment: @Max thank you. If you want to answer. I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `In-Reply-To` and `References` headers are for the convenience of email clients to group related emails together as threads or conversations.  The replying client puts them there to chain the emails together. These headers are described in [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) § 3.6.4.

The quoted text in the body is placed there by the replying client as a convenience for the human reader. It is not automatic<sup>1</sup>, and there's not a standard for it.

<sup>1</sup> Not for IMAP, POP3, and SMTP anyway. Some proprietary protocols (such as Exchange Active Sync) may include a "smart reply" feature which will do some of the work on behalf of the client.